# What's a microcontroller "ordering code"?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm shopping for an ATtiny13A microcontroller for an Instructable, and I see lots of them offered online, but none are named just "ATtiny13A" — they're all things like:

- ATtiny13A-PU
- ATtiny13A-SU
- ATtiny13A-MMU
  ...etc.

On the manufacturer's page these are listed as Ordering Codes: http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY13A.aspx

Do I need something specific or are they all interchangable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's in page 11 of the summary datasheet.  The suffix refers to the package, among other things:

[image]

Comment: What does "package" mean in this context, and do I have to consider it when choosing a model?

Comment: package is physical form in which chip is present, like thru hole or smd with 8 legs or super small smd with 5 legs.

Comment: you probably should get something with PU for ATtiny - it's a standard old school chip with legs

Comment: The datasheet is always the best place for the most definitive information, but they're listed in more readable form on http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY13A.aspx.  Check this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BN7z5.png.

Comment: Excellent, thanks – your responses led me to this list of integrated circuit packaging types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrated_circuit_packaging_types